# Open source platform/software to develop app backend

Tags: open-source, mobile-application, custom-backend

We are going to develop some mobile app for one of our clients, and we are defining the technical solution for the backend server.

Basically, we need to implement a backend providing REST apis for the apps. The apps will need features such as user authentication, handling of user profiles and user contents. The backend should also expose a web administration interface and allow to manipulate some of the app contents in a CMS-like way.

My client specifically wants to avoid baas solution (like Parse), and I am trying to find some open source software able to provide some of the features out of the box, to avoid writing everything from scratch, and develop the other parts. We can use cloud services such as AWS for hosting the backend.

What existing platform/software would you advise?

Answer (score 4):

Here a a few options to look into:

- DreamFactory: http://www.dreamfactory.com/
- Loopback: http://loopback.io/
- Apache Usergrid: http://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/
- BaasBox: http://www.baasbox.com/

Not sure if this answer your question. Did you come across other options?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using apache usergrid for one of my projects and consider it powerful on following areas;

- Authentication & Authorization (also social login)
- Activity creation and activity feeds
- Asset storage (local or aws s3)
- Dynamic collection creation
- Search on collections and support custom query language (via elastic search)

But it doesn't support push notifications. If you need that out of the box, you may have a look at BaasBox. It seems a good alternative to usergrid.

I didn't find documentation adequate for usergrid (i mean for internals not api usage), so you have to dig source code to find out answers.

If you are developing social application (user activities, feeds, comments, likes) it is hard to update counters in a document (e.g. updating comments and likes count). It is not natively supported. You may sync increments on the same document using a queue like kafka.